# Call New Activity from MAin Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want, that when you click to open a new screen (Activity), but have a problem, the new screen does not open. What changes are made ​​to the code, so that the new window opened?

```
package com.android.yalt;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  Button btnny;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnny = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ny);
    btnny.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ny:
        startActivity(NY.class);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }

private void startActivity(Class<NY> class2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NY.class));
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NY.class);
startActivity(i);
```

or In a method format:

```
 public void startMyActivity(Class activityToStart){
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), activityToStart.class));
    }
```

Just as a sidenote, one can replace getBaseContext() with your own context if one wants to e.g. `startActivity(new Intent(yourOnGoingActivityGoesHere.this, yourClassGoesHere.class));`

Also as a utility:

```
/*This is not tested but should work */
public class AndroidUtility(){
/**
 *Usage: AndroidUtility.startMyActivity(MainActivity.this, NY.class);
 */
public static void startMyActivity(Activity onGoingActivity, Class activityToStart){
onGoingActivity.startActivity(new Intent(onGoingActivity.getBaseContext(), activityToStart.class));


   }
}
```

In your case the easiest would be:

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ny:
          startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NY.class));
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
```